# Can't sync south in db

Tags: django, django-south

I am having trouble to sync south in my project. And the error its giving me is to use `./manage.py.` I am on windows, so I can't do `chmod +x manage.py`. Is there any way around to do `./manage.py` in windows, or how do i sync south in windows. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if your `python.exe` in the system PATH and then, in your project directory from `cmd.exe` you can run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: Yes, its in my system path.

Comment: So could you try to run in your `cmd.exe` command: `python C:/path/to/your/project/manage.py syncdb`? Also check if south in you app INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Ok, i think it did some part of it. In one line it says, `Creating table south_migrationhistory`. And in "Synced:", it has `south`. But its showing one more error now. `Not synced (use migration): -- article` which by the way is an app in my project. Please guide me, what do i do next?

Comment: @Robin, so now you created table `south_migrationhistory` which will contain all migrations order etc. data. Now you can apply your apps migrations. Use `python manage.py migrate` to migrate all applications or `python manage.py migrate app_name` to migrate only `app_name` application. Also you can inspect your apps for `migrations` directory, there should be 0001_initial.py, 0002 or something like this. If not, try to create initial migrations: `python manage.py schemamigration app_name --initial` and then apply it, as I describe above. Also check this: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks it did helped!!! Just one more question though, how do i do
./manage.py --fake <app_name>?

Comment: @Robin, like previous commands: `python manage.py migrate <app_name> 0001 --fake`